# WCF SOAP Service add datatypes in response to complex types

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I have a WCF SOAP Service in C# that runs perfect. But now I want to add the Datatypes to the SOAP Response.

If I return an array of boolean or string I get something like:

```
<a:elements xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <b:string>ID</b:string>
      <b:string>Description</b:string>
      <b:string>Material</b:string>
      <b:string>Price</b:string>
  </a:elements>
```

or

```
<a:updatePermissions xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <b:boolean>true</b:boolean>
      <b:boolean>false</b:boolean>
      <b:boolean>false</b:boolean>
      <b:boolean>false</b:boolean>
    </a:updatePermissions >
```

But if I send a complex type i get something like

```
<a:Elements>
      <a:Material>
        <a:Id>465</a:Id>
        <a:Description>TestAddMaterial</a:Description>
        <a:MaterialId>1</a:MaterialId>
        <a:PriceForKg>0.03</a:PriceForKg>
      </a:Material>
</a:Elements>
```

How can I convert the response of complex types like the response of an array?

Something like:

```
    <a:Elements>
      <a:Material>
        <a:integer>465</a:integer>
        <a:string>TestAddMaterial</a:string>
        <a:integer>1</a:integer>
        <a:double>0.03</a:double>
     </a:Material>
    </a:Elements>
```

The name of the Variable is not necessary at this point.

The class itselfe is a DataContract with DataMember.

Comment: In my opinion that would go against best practise and I'm not sure its really possible, not without a considerable amount of work I would imagine.

Comment: Okay, what would you recommend to get the type? is there a simple way to add the type as an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can return [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx). Any custom XML option would require you to build the XML yourself.

As an example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISomeService
{
   [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
   XmlElement SomeMethod(XmlElement someParameter);
}
```

You may also use the DocumentElement property of an [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) instance as the default DataContractSerializer can serialize [XmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx) instances.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx

Though the above options are not standard practice. Instead you should be using a [DataContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx) and it should be structured in the way you want it to be serialized into XML. When the service method returns the custom type, WCF will serialize it into an XML document implicitly.